# What do the different difficulties mean?

Tags: story-of-seasons

When starting a new game, I am given the option to select a difficulty. "Original" and "seedling". What are the differences in these difficulties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original mode is exactly that; what previous Harvest Moon games had.

Seedling mode makes the game slightly easier:

- It lowers the cost of buying items and upgrades by 30%.
- Tools use half the stamina.
- For the last couple of trade vendors, it lowers the requirements to unlock them.

[Source](http://fogu.com/sos1/basics/difficulty-modes.php)

Comment: The difficulty level of the various Harvest Moon games has varied quite a bit. Original means the difficulty level of the original Japanese release of Story of Seasons (Bokujou Monogatari: Tsunagaru Shin Tenchi). That original release was was apparently unusually difficult, so a patch was made available in Japan that added the second, easier, difficulty level.

Comment: It's worth noting that the 30% discount only applies to town shops. It does not apply to trade depot vendors.